# How to check is repo is in "dirty" status asynchronously? (For prompt)

Tags: git, command-prompt, fish

I have an usual displaying of info from GIT like current branch name, and is repo is in "dirty" state within prompt. The problem is that some larger repos take a good few seconds to calculate the "dirty" state.

Is there a way to issue the dirty check asynchronously, to not hold down the responsiveness of shell?
PS I'am using `fish 2.0` shell.

Comment: When you say "usual displaying of info" do you mean - in your shell prompt (I've never used `fish`)?

Comment: @nickgrim yes, I mean shell prompt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `git diff-index --quiet HEAD --`, it will stop processing at the first diff encountered instead of processing the entire source tree, so that may help you with execution time.

In addition, you can use a temporary buffer for your current dirty state, such as a file in /tmp.
Then, your prompt command will take the content of that file and use it in the prompt, after which it will launch a background update to the repo (such as `git diff-index --quiet HEAD -- && echo clean >/tmp/myreponame.status || echo dirty >/tmp/myreponame.status &`).

One thing you should be careful with is that the background update will be launched for *every* prompt, meaning you may end up with several of those running at the same time. To avoid that, you'll need a script that checks if it's already running and either quits or kills the older instance.